# How to compute precision-recall in Decision tree sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I try to predict in standard dataset "iris.csv"

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import tree
df = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
df.columns = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'Y']
df.head()

# Decision tree
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
decision = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini')
X = df.values[:, 0:4]
Y = df.values[:, 4]
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.25)
decision.fit(trainX, trainY)
y_score = decision.score(testX, testY)
print('Accuracy: ', y_score)


# Compute the average precision score
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score
average_precision = average_precision_score(testY, y_score)

print('Average precision-recall score: {0:0.2f}'.format(
      average_precision))
```

And i have valueerror

```
File "C:/Users/Ultra/PycharmProjects/poker_ML/decision_tree.py", line 20, in <module>
    average_precision = average_precision_score(testY, y_score)
  File "C:\Users\Ultra\PycharmProjects\poker_ML\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\ranking.py", line 241, in average_precision_score
    average, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "C:\Users\Ultra\PycharmProjects\poker_ML\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\base.py", line 74, in _average_binary_score
    raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

How can I compute precision-recall for 3 class?
How works precision-recall for decision tree in sklearn. Maybe I have a mistake in calculation "y_score"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [scikit-learn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html) `average_precision_score` cannot handle multiclass classification.

Instead, you may use [`precision_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_score.html) like this:

```
# Decision tree
...
y_pred = decision.predict(testX)
y_score = decision.score(testX, testY)
print('Accuracy: ', y_score)

# Compute the average precision score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score
micro_precision = precision_score(y_pred, testY, average='micro')
print('Micro-averaged precision score: {0:0.2f}'.format(
      micro_precision))

macro_precision = precision_score(y_pred, testY, average='macro')
print('Macro-averaged precision score: {0:0.2f}'.format(
      macro_precision))

per_class_precision = precision_score(y_pred, testY, average=None)
print('Per-class precision score:', per_class_precision)
```

Note, that you need to specify how to average the scores. This is especially relevant, if your dataset shows label imbalance (which `iris` does not).